# Wrong company domain on a new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am starting a new project in Android Studio, this time with a different domain for the project.

In my last project I used domain1 and now I need to use domain2. When I did the first run I received the message below in the Debug window.

The new project is using the domain of the last project. I tried to clean the project and even make a new project from begining but the error persists. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

(I changed the domains names for best reading)

> br.com.domain1 --> used in the last project (**Project1**)
>
> br.com.domain2 --> used in this project (**Project2**)

Debug window:

```
08/15 10:04:51: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\User1\AndroidstudioProjects\Project2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/br.com.Domain1.Project2
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/br.com.Domain1.Project2"
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/br.com.Domain1.Project2
Success

$ adb shell am start -D -n "br.com.Domain1.Project2/br.com.Domain2.Project2.PrincipalActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -D -n "br.com.Domain1.Project2/br.com.Domain2.Project2.PrincipalActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=br.com.Domain1.Project2/br.com.Domain2.Project2.PrincipalActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {br.com.Domain1.Project2/br.com.Domain2.Project2.PrincipalActivity} does not exist.
Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Do a search and check if 'domain1' has been replaced with 'domain2' everywhere (gradle, manifest, package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after pressing *Sync Project with Gradle Files* button in Android Studio main toolbar. :-(